# How to cast an array made up of user-defined value types to the underlying type in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, user-defined-value-types

I have an array which is made up of [user-defined value types](https://blog.soliditylang.org/2021/09/27/user-defined-value-types):

```
type UD60x18 is uint256;
UD60x18 memory foo[] = new UD60x18[](2);
```

Now, I would like to turn this into `uint256`. Can I cast this array to `uint256[]` without creating another variable?

Comment: According to this comment (https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/11531#issuecomment-910401889) it doesn't seem possible for now...  It's only one line to do that conversion in assembly though.

Comment: @hroussille do you know how to do that in assembly? I wouldn't mind using Yul.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your comment, the following function would do that conversion using assembly :

```
// Since UD60x18 is uint256 their underlying size and representation are the same
// Just make a uint256[] reference point to your UD60x18[] memory variable
function unwrapArray(UD60x18[] memory foo) internal pure returns (uint256[] memory bar) {
    assembly {
        bar := foo
    }
}
```

Thus, this would return a `uint256[]` with values [1, 2] :

```
function test() public pure returns (uint256[] memory) {
    UD60x18[] memory foo = new UD60x18[](2);
    foo[0] = UD60x18.wrap(1);
    foo[1] = UD60x18.wrap(2);
    return unwrapArray(foo); // [1, 2]
}
```

It does create a new variable though... As far as I know of, there is no implicit or explicit conversion allowed for used defined value types currently.